# Disable alert rule with empty TargetResourceRegion

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am trying to disable an alert rule via powershell, but I am getting the following error:

```
Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroupname"  -Name "alertname" | Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -DisableRule
```

> Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2: Cannot validate argument on parameter
> 'TargetResourceRegion'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
> argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

I have tried it without the | Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -DisableRule:

```
Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroupname"  -Name "alertname"
Output:
Criteria             : {Metric1}
Actions              : {/subscriptions/subscriptionguid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroupname/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/actiongroupname}
ResourceGroup        : myresourcegroupname
Description          :
Severity             : 3
Enabled              : True
Scopes               : {/subscriptions/subscriptionguid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/myservername/elasticpools/myelasticpoolname}
EvaluationFrequency  : 00:01:00
WindowSize           : 00:01:00
TargetResourceType   : Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools
TargetResourceRegion :
AutoMitigate         : True
LastUpdatedTime      :
IsMigrated           :
Id                   : /subscriptions/3subscriptionguid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroupname/providers/microsoft.insights/metricAlerts/alertname
Name                 : alertname
Type                 : Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts
Location             : global
Tags                 : {}
Kind                 :
Etag                 :
```

My previous command was telling me that 'TargetResourceRegion' is null or empty. And that's right corresponding to the output above. But how can I disable that alert rule from powershell, with an empty TargetResourceRegion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tested this in our local environment, Below statements are based on our analysis.

As per the **[Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/add-azmetricalertrulev2?view=azps-7.1.0)** cmdlet documentation, `-DisableRule` parameter is of Type **Switch Parameter** it does not require any input parameter to be passed.

In our local environment, we have created an alert for webapp & we are able
to disable the alert using the below PowerShell Cmdlet

```
Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ResourceGroup '<ResourceGroupName> -Name '<NameofAlert>'|Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -DisableRule
```

***Here is the sample output screenshot for reference:***

- Initially, we have pulled a specific alert by using `Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2`

[image]

- Ran the same cmdlet, by adding the `|Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2` to disable a specific metric alert rule.

[image]

**Updated Answer:**

We have also tested this cmdlet for sql elastic pools in our local environment, using the below cmdlet we are able to disable the alert.

```
Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ResourceGroupName '<resourcegrp>' -Name '<AlertName>'|Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -DisableRule -TargetResourceRegion " "
```

**Here is the sample screenshot for reference:**

[image]

Comment: I have tested it again. For an alert for a webapp it's working. But not for my elastic pool alert rule.

Comment: @1408786user Please refer my above Updated Answer

Comment: That's working. I just got it working with -TargetResourceRegion "global" but it's also working as how you have suggested.